# How to wrap a list item in a link_to?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, only the text is clickable and is taking the user to the specified route in the application, while clicking on any other part of the li dropdown results in nothing.

Here is the code:

```
<li id='dropdown'>
    <%= current_user.email %> ▾
        <ul id='dropdown-list'>
             <li> <%= link_to "My Account", current_user %> </li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log Out", session_path("current"), method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the css:

```
#dropdown-list {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #bcbfc3;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

#dropdown-list li { 
  background: #fff; 
  display: block; 
  color: #7D818A;
}
#dropdown-list li:hover{
 background-color: #ECECEE; 
}

#dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `link_to` by creating a block like this:

```
<%= link_to(current_user) do %>
...stuff to wrap here...
<%=end%>
```

I think you'll probably want something like this:

```
<li id='dropdown'>
    <%= current_user.email %> ▾
        <ul id='dropdown-list'>
          <%= link_to(current_user) do %>
             <li>My Account</li>
          <%= end %>
            <li><%= link_to "Log Out", session_path("current"), method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, [a list should only contain list items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). This **probably** won't hurt compatibility too much, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Solution:

```
#dropdown-list>li>a{
  display: block;
}
```